# What exactly am I doing wrong with my wordcount program? (pig)

Tags: apache-pig

I'm very unfamiliar with pig, I wanted to attempt to make a sorted word count that took in no punctuation.  I can DUMP D just fine, the issue comes when I attempt to DUMP E and get this error.

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias E

A = load './SherlockHolmes.txt' using PigStorage(' ');
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(LOWER((chararray)$0),'([A-Za-z]+)')) as word;
C = group B by word;
D = foreach C generate COUNT(B) AS counts, group AS word;
E = ORDER D BY counts DESC;
DUMP E;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of pig are you using?  I just tried this in version 0.10, and it worked, but it gave incorrect output.

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this answer I'll be using this as my sample input:

```
Hello, my ;name is Holmes.                                                       
This is a test, of a question on SO.                                            
Holmes, again.
```

When I'm writing a script for the first time, I find it really helpful to [`DESCRIBE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#describe) and [`DUMP`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#dump) each step with some sample data so I know exactly what is happening.  Doing that with your script shows:

```
A = load './SherlockHolmes.txt' using PigStorage(' ');
-- Schema for A unknown.
-- (Hello,,my,name,is,Holmes.)
-- (This,is,a,test,,of,a,question,on,SO.)
-- (Holmes,,again.)
```

So the output from `A` is a 'tuple' (really it is a schema) with an unknown number of values.  Generally, if you don't know how may values are in a tuple, you should use a [bag](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#bag) instead.

```
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(LOWER((chararray)$0),'([A-Za-z]+)')) as word;
-- B: {word: bytearray}
-- ()
-- (this)
-- ()
```

When you use `$0` you are referring not to all of the words in the schema, but rather the first word.  So you are only applying the `LOWER` and `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` to the first word.  Also, note that the [`FLATTEN`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#flatten) operator is being done on a tuple, with does not produce the output that you want.  You want to `FLATTEN` a bag.

`C`, `D`, and `E` all should work as you expect, so it all about massaging the data to get into a format that they can use.

Knowing this, you can do it like this:

```
-- Load in the line as a chararray so that TOKENIZE can convert it into a bag
A = load './tests/sh.txt' AS (foo:chararray);

B1 = FOREACH A GENERATE TOKENIZE(foo, ' ') AS tokens: {T:(word: chararray)} ;
-- Output from B1:
-- B1: {tokens: {T: (word: chararray)}}
-- ({(Hello,),(my),(;name),(is),(Holmes.)})
-- ({(This),(is),(a),(test,),(of),(a),(question),(on),(SO.)})
-- ({(Holmes,),(again.)})

-- Now inside a nested FOREACH we apply the appropriate transformations.
B2 = FOREACH B1 {

    -- Inside a nested FOREACH you can go over the contents of a bag
    cleaned = FOREACH tokens GENERATE 
              -- The .*? are needed to capture the leading and trailing punc.
              FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(LOWER(word),'.*?([a-z]+).*?')) as word ;

    -- Cleaned is a bag, so when we FLATTEN it we get one word per line
    GENERATE FLATTEN(cleaned) ;
}
```

So now the output of `B2` is:

```
B2: {cleaned::word: bytearray}
(hello)
(my)
(name)
(is)
(holmes)
(this)
(is)
(a)
(test)
(of)
(a)
(question)
(on)
(so)
(holmes)
(again)
```

Which, when feed into `C`, `D`, and `E`, will give the desired output.

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Comment: And here I thought pig was supposed to be simpler :P

Comment: Anyway thank you for the help... I really would have never realized all of this

Comment: Simularish question for a different problem, why does this refuse to be ordered?

Comment: grunt> Describe C         
C: {count: long,group: chararray}

Comment: You mean the output of `E`?  For me the output of `E` is sorted in descending order, so I'm not really sure.  The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is that `counts` is being treated like a chararray instead of a long/int.

Comment: If that is whats causing my issues how would I avoid it?

Comment: After seeing the output of the `DESCRIBE C;`, the type shouldn't be causing the issue.  This seems like it needs its own question.  Make sure to provide the relevant `DESCRIBE`s and `DUMP`s for it!